# Android: Which date picker was clicked

Tags: android, date, datepicker, back

I have ***two*** date pickers in the ***same activity***

when the user click back button on device, the system suppose to know which date picker date was changed by the user

and to be aware:

> The two date pickers are connected and when the user change one picker
>   date the other picker date change also in a specific way depending on
>   the first picker

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: given that *you* start the date picker, *you* know which you started. right ?

Comment: I have two date pickers in the same activity

Comment: Just save the initial date of both datepicker. When backpressed check current date value with the saved one.

Comment: This is not possible because the two date pickers are connected and when the user change one picker date the other picker date change also in a specific way depending on the first picker

Comment: Do the same. You'll know which one or both is changed when leaving the activity. Or if you want to identify which one is changed and change other one accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but I think this should work:

```
private DatePicker datePicker1;
private DatePicker datePicker2;
//...
OnDateChangedListener listener = new OnDateChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {

          if (datePicker1.equals(view)) {
               // Date of datePicker1 is changed
               // ...
          }
          else if (datePicker2.equals(view)) {
               // Date of datePicker2 is changed
               // ...
          }
}

datePicker1.init(2012, 11, 27, listener);
datePicker2.init(2012, 11, 27, listener);
```

Comment: How is that, can you explain more please

Comment: onDateChanged is called with the "DatePicker view" which tells you which DatePicker is calling it..

Comment: datePicker1.equals(view) means what ?

Comment: `datePicker1.equals(view)` returns true if `datePicker1` is the one has its date changed.

Comment: but as I said , the two date pickers date will be changed as they are connected, I just want to know which one was changed by user